# Correct english term for an urgent referral

Tags: emergency

I am translating a Swedish text, and I am having problems translating the term "akutremiss" to British English. The term is commonly used in Swedish healthcare. It is basically a referral, of any type, where the medical issue is urgent. I have done some basic googling on some of the options, just to see which ones are the most commonly used.

```
GOOGLE SEARCHES AND HIT COUNTS

healthcare "acute referral"
19 700

healthcare "emergency referral"
95 400

healthcare "urgent referral"
56 800
```

The clear winner is "Emergency referral". "Urgent referral" is the runner up. But I feel there is a big difference in the level of urgency between "urgent" and "emergency", with an emergency being *way* more urgent than something which is just "urgent", at least to my ears.

Note: I included "acute referral", mostly because it is a direct translation of the Swedish term, but it sounds really strange to me. I have never heard anyone use the word "acute" to mean "urgent". The pages I checked seem to be mostly about eye damage, so perhaps the term is eyes-only (pun intended).

What are some thoughts? Is there anything like an "official" term used in the healthcare community?

Comment: Check site:uk, gov.uk and co.uk

Comment: At least in US English, "emergency" (or "emergent") is _not_ synonymous with "urgent." If the Swedish word means "urgent" then that's what I would go with. It makes perfect sense in US English and I suspect UK English as well.